# Can I make a strong typed integer in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11

I would like a strong typed integer in C++ that compiles in Visual Studio 2010.

I need this type to act like an integer in some templates. In particular I need to be able to:

```
StrongInt x0(1);                  //construct it.
auto x1 = new StrongInt[100000];  //construct it without initialization
auto x2 = new StrongInt[10]();    //construct it with initialization
```

I have seen things like:

```
class StrongInt
{ 
    int value;
public: 
    explicit StrongInt(int v) : value(v) {} 
    operator int () const { return value; } 
};
```

or

```
class StrongInt
{ 
    int value;
public: 
    StrongInt() : value(0) {} //fails 'construct it without initialization
    //StrongInt() {} //fails 'construct it with initialization
    explicit StrongInt(int v) : value(v) {} 
    operator int () const { return value; } 
};
```

Since these things are not POD's, they do not quite work.

Comment: Well, it needs a no-argument constructor for the array, and it needs an assignment operator to assign the actual value, and then that'd be about it. Am I missing something?

Comment: @jyoung Don't want to be picky, but as far as I know, in C++ you _have to_ specify a type after the `auto` keyword.

Comment: @EitanT -- in C++11 they recycled the `auto` keyword to mean something new -- now it means "automatically deduce the type". It's kind of silly to use it here, but it's really handy for complex template type names that are hard to type.

Comment: @Fanael,@Ernest I didn't see no C++0X/C++11 tag * *Z-snaps fingers dismissively* *

Comment: @EitanT: I do see the [visual-studio-2010] tag, and VC10 compiler does support new `auto`.

Comment: Okay. Retagged, just in case. Also, I am missing a default constructor here, or at least a default value for `(int v = 0)`. Am I correct?

Comment: @Ernest Depending on how you write the no argument constructor, it fails either the 'construct it without initialization' or the 'construct it with initialization' line

Comment: @jyoung It [compiles](http://ideone.com/B3Qvh), if there's a default constructor or a default value for `int v`.

Comment: @EitanT: In case you hadn't heard, this code is now standard-compliant.  The C++11 tag isn't strictly necessary (and seems pointless, because the use or non-use of `auto` doesn't affect the question in any way).

Comment: @BenVoigt I haven't been updated on the "revamped" `auto` keyword, but in C++03 it doesn't compile, so I felt the necessity to tag it as C++11. But you're right about it being irrelevant to the question itself.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: I disagree that it's silly to use it here. The alternative is to pointlessly repeat the type: `StrongInt * x1 = new StrongInt[100000]`. `auto` is the logical extension of "Don't Repeat Yourself"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just use an enumeration type when I want a strongly-typed integer.

```
enum StrongInt { _min = 0, _max = INT_MAX };

StrongInt x0 = StrongInt(1);
int i = x0;
```

Comment: How is something that's implicitly convertible to any integer type strongly-typed? `enum class` might have made sense...

Comment: The OP's example were implicitly convertible to integers too, plus it meets the requirements for being easily (un)initialized. Enumeration types are not convertible to each other, so `enum StrongInt` and `enum Price` and `enum Quantity` are all distinct types that are not convertible to each other and can be used for overloading and specialization. Using enums as distinct integer types is a great technique, though I'm always surprised it's not more commonly used.

Comment: @Jonathan I get a compiler error:  StrongInt x0(1); =>error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'StrongInt'. ---- However I can fix compile time errors by changing my code to StrongInt x0 = StrongInt(1), whereas I could not accept having hidden uninitialized or performance problems at runtime. So I am accepting this answer.

Comment: @ildjarn I had this tagged as VS-2010. That compiler does not support enum class. Someone had issues with my use of the keyword auto and incorrectly added the C++11 tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
StrongInt x0(1);
```

> Since these things are not POD's, they do not quite work.

These two things are incompatible: you can't have both constructor syntax and PODness. For a POD you'd need to use e.g. `StrongInt x0 { 1 };` or `StrongInt x0 = { 1 };`, or even `StrongInt x0({ 1 });` (that's a very round-about copy-initialization).